# Copy war dependency mentioned in maven jar module

Tags: maven

The war dependency mentioned in jar project just to get copied from copy-dependency plugin/assembly plugin to use for some custom packaging. But plugin skip the war dependency , Is this plugin behaviour?
or need something else?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.external.modules</groupId>
  <artifactId>war-jboss</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you show your pom file?

Comment: Hey this is working fine as i excluded pattern with war-* so it is not copied . Now i find it , issue is solve. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven assembly plugin works on include and exclude. You would not be including your war file correctly. Check if you are using the correct regular expressions to include the war file in assembly plugin.

Comment: Any idea how I could [include a `war` into a `jar`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052996/how-to-build-single-jar-and-keep-dependencies-intact) correctly?